PRF with a one truly random evaluation
A pseudorandom function $f_k: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$ has the property that for any probabilistic polynomial time adversary $\mathcal{A}$,
$$|Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{f_k(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] - \underset{h \gets \mathcal{H}}{Pr} [\mathcal{A}^{h(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]| = negl(\lambda)$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ is the set of all functions $h:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$ and $\lambda$ is the security parameter. I was wondering whether it is possible to show that for any probabilistic polynomial time adversary $\mathcal{A}$,
$$|Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{f_k(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] - Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] = 1]| = negl(\lambda)$$
where the oracle $O$ is stateful with the following description. For the first query (which we denote as $x^*$), $O(k,x^*)$ outputs a truly random value $t \in \{0,1\}^m$ and for the remaining queries where $x \neq x^*$,  $O(k,x) = f_k(x)$ (if $x = x^*$, it outputs $t$). In other words, $O$ simulates a PRF but one of its evaluations is a truly random value. I know we can build PRFs with such properties (programmable PRFs), but my question is with regards to any PRF.
To me, it feels that it should be true, but how would one formally argue it?

Thanks for this self answered Q/A. But I'm a bit curious, how did you write "To me, it feels that it should be true, but how would one formally argue it?" and immediately answer afterwards?

@MaartenBodewes Frankly speaking, I didn't come up with the answer immediately. The reason why I felt it should be true is from the security definition of PRF. If all the evaluations of the PRF are pseudorandom (meaning computationally indistinguishable), then it does not matter whether a few of them are truly random and the rest are pseudorandom. Then, I figured that triangular inequality would help. Essentially, if we can go from all pseudorandom to all truly random, then we can have multiple hybrids where the ith hybrid will have first i truly random values and the remaining pseudorandom.

From the definition, we have
$$\left|(Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{f_k(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] - Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]) +  (Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]- \underset{h \gets \mathcal{H}}{Pr} [\mathcal{A}^{h(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]) \right| = negl(\lambda)$$
If we are able to show that $|Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]- \underset{h \gets \mathcal{H}}{Pr} [\mathcal{A}^{h(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]| = negl(\lambda)$, then by triangular inequality, we would get $$|Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{f_k(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] - Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1] = 1]| = negl(\lambda)$$
To show that $|Pr_{k}[\mathcal{A}^{O(k,\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]- \underset{h \gets \mathcal{H}}{Pr} [\mathcal{A}^{h(\cdot)}(1^{\lambda}) = 1]| = negl(\lambda)$, we will prove that an adversary (denoted as $\mathcal{A}^*$) that wins with significant advantage can be used to build an adversary $\mathcal{B}$ that breaks the PRF security. $\mathcal{B}$ will be given an oracle access $Q$ to either a PRF function or a truly random function. It will invoke $\mathcal{A}^*$ and respond to its first query $x^*$ with a truly random value $t$. For the remaining queries, it will invoke $Q$ (or use $t$ if the query was $x^*$). Observe that if $Q$ was a truly random function, then $\mathcal{B}$ has simulated a truly random function for $\mathcal{A}^*$. Otherwise, it has simulated $O$ for $\mathcal{A}^*$. Therefore, $\mathcal{B}$ would win with the same advantage.
